# a is '0.0.0.0' how to get the combination of ips from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 using builtin or any logic python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I tried with the links provided as duplicate but its not working as expected
A = '0.0.0.0' 
Z = '255.255.255.255'
how to get the combination of ips from A - Z ie 0.0.0.0 to 
255.255.255.255 using builtin or any logic using  python

Comment: Not a duplicate i tried those logic in above links but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this, which generates all possible pairs from `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`

```
import itertools

li = range(0,256)

#Generate all possible combinations of numbers from 0 to 255, in a pair of 4
for t in itertools.product(li,repeat=4):
    print(f'{t[0]}.{t[1]}.{t[2]}.{t[3]}')
```

Output will be

```
.....
0.1.121.217
0.1.121.218
0.1.121.219
0.1.121.220
0.1.121.221
0.1.121.222
0.1.121.223
0.1.121.224
......
```

Comment: Thanks devesh this is what i was looking for...thanks lot

Comment: accepted it , am not sure someone had told that its duplicate but only your logic worked fine as i wanted and i tried the duplicate link sugg logic but its not working as i want.due to this someone gave negative votes..

Comment: cool thanks lot.. :)

Comment: Can you please explain your code, because the output does not look correct.  Thanks.

Comment: The explanation is already added, the code generates all possible IP’s . The output I showed is only part of those possible IP’s